# Reading CDATA from XML file with BeautifulSoup

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have tweets saved in an XML file as:

```
<tweet>
  <tweetid>142389495503925248</tweetid>
  <user>ccifuentes</user>
  <content><![CDATA[Salgo de #VeoTV , que día más largoooooo...]]></content>
  <date>2011-12-02T00:47:55</date>
  <lang>es</lang>
  <sentiments>
   <polarity><value>NONE</value><type>AGREEMENT</type></polarity>
  </sentiments>
  <topics>
   <topic>otros</topic>
  </topics>
 </tweet>
```

To parse these, I created a BeautifulSoup instance via

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
```

where xml is the raw XML file. To access a single tweet I did this:

```
tweets = soup.find_all('tweet')
for tw in tweets:
    print(tw)
    break
```

This results in

```
<tweet>
<tweetid>142389495503925248</tweetid>
<user>ccifuentes</user>
<content></content>
<date>2011-12-02T00:47:55</date>
<lang>es</lang>
<sentiments>
<polarity><value>NONE</value><type>AGREEMENT</type></polarity>
</sentiments>
<topics>
<topic>otros</topic>
</topics>
</tweet>
```

Note that the CDATA part was omitted when I printed the first tweet. It is important for me to get it, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
```

change the parser to `xml`

out:

```
<content>Salgo de #VeoTV , que día más largoooooo...</content>
```

OR `html.parser`:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')
```

out:

```
<content><![CDATA[Salgo de #VeoTV , que día más largoooooo...]]></content>
```

Comment: Cheers, what is the main difference between the parsers?

Comment: @Vladimir Vargas different parser act differently in some parts of data type, in most case, they are all the same.